# Can't run & create a class on Eclipse because my clone is not a project

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github, repository

[image]I have a problem on a git project that I cloned on eclipse, I can't run it and create a class in this project, when I try to create a class, eclipse tells me that it's not a project , How can I fix this? I tried window preferences, java editor, but it still doesn't work, I uninstalled eclipse it still doesn't work, the problem probably comes from the project but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Not everything Java is built using Eclipse. From which url did you clone the repository?

Comment: @g00se https://gaufre.informatique.univ-paris-diderot.fr/abdorohm/projets4.git

Comment: Unfortunately that requires a login

Comment: Create a new Java project and copy the *.java files into the source folder.

Comment: @g00se sorry i cant turn on public mmmh, i can send u my project

Comment: @howlger i don't understand, where is the source folder ?

Comment: The upshot of all this is going to be creating a new project and building it from your source

Comment: In a new Java project the source folder is by default `src`.

Comment: @g00se here the project https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3eff950b7043b27dcf729784e5d1438820230213153249/3b59ecc14a09a9369442223118acbff620230213153249/0e4594 if u import it on eclipse, u cant run it, in vs code we can but i want to code in exlipse and push it on github.

Comment: A git repository should contain only source files (*.java), no code compiled (*.class). I would recommend you to create a Java project from scratch in eclipse, and then copy the *.java files in source folder.

Comment: @kev ok, how do i link the new project with git so i can push

Comment: I wouldn't tie your project to a particular IDE. That's only going to make it less likely to appeal to users of different IDEs. I would make a Maven project and use that for your repro

Comment: *repo  not "repro"